# editing prism models in emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there any emacs package that supports prism language? (http://www.prismmodelchecker.org/)
I would like to edit prism models (dtmc, ctmc ..) in emacs
because editing directly using xprism take more time for me

Thank you very much

Comment: The `prism` tag has nothing to do with what you are asking in this question. Please, use tags appropriately.